# WCF Callback for choosing SSL Client Cert

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, client-certificates

I have the following code:

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.RequestClient();
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = 
     new X509Certificate2( "c:\\tmp\\cert.pfx" );
```

That sets the SSL Client cert for my WCF connection. However, this happens before I know which acceptable roots are being sent from the server (in CertificateRequest).

Is there a callback, similar to the ServerCertValidation callback:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =  
   ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

That will allow me to get the list of acceptable root, and choose a client cert based upon that information?

Comment: You seem to be mixing client certificate and server certificate. SSL certificate is on the server so you cannot load it in client?!

Comment: I think you might not understand SSL. "SSL Certificates" can exist both on the client and server. You have "Server" certificates that most people understand. You can (optionally) have the server authenticate the client by requesting a Client Certificate. First, the server sends its certificate, which the client validates (hence the optional callback). Then the server can send a request to the client to have the client send the server a cert (for authentication). The server sends a list of acceptable CA's for the client to choose from. By default, schannel picks the first acceptable cert.

Comment: You are right. RFC 5246 refers to client certificate as well. I did not know that. But to say I do not understand SSL, well, is a bit rude - to be frank.

Comment: Mea culpa. It wasn't my intention to offend. Forgive me.

Comment: is there a way out ? .. I too need to authenticate client.. Currently I am using CertificationValidationMode = Custom and using customvalidator for the certifcate.. Is there a way out or better solution instead.. Coz I need exact Status error for ex Invalid Digital Signature ..